British mini series set in 18th century
I am looking for a TV mini series which I remember seeing, but I have no idea what it is called.
Here is what I remember about the show:

Set in 18th century England (could be 17th or 19th)
I think the show was 6 or 8 episodes.
Show aired (in Denmark at least) in 2003; so probably aired in UK before that.
The shows main characters were employees of noble families working on a large mansions/castles/farms or the like; everything from the maids, kitchen staff to butlers and young men (I don't know english term for young men hired on castles to help out in the fields, working with horses etc.?).
I remember their uniforms as being green velvet (but I may remember wrong).

This is pretty much everything I remember. 
Anyone have a clue which show it could be?
